# "Could not connect to SMTP host" error using Ant <mail> task

Tags: java, email, ant

I am getting the below error with the Ant `<mail>` task when trying to send a TestNG report from a Windows 7 machine with JDK1.8.

> [mail] Failed to send email: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.easycgi.com, port:587

I have searched on Google, and some forums recommend placing mail.jar and activation.jar in `%ANT_HOME%/lib` which I have already done.

Telnet to SMTP is positive.

Using:

- JDK1.8
- Windows7
- Ant 1.9.5
- mail-1.4.7
- Activation-1.1

Ant task:

```
<mail enableStartTLS="true" ssl="true" mailhost="smtp.easycgi.com" mailport="587"
    user="user@test.com" password="******" subject="Test build">
    <from address="fromadress@test.com"/>  
    <to address="toaddress@test.com"/>
    <message>TestNG Report for suite1</message>
    <attachments>
        <fileset dir="dist">
            <include name="**/*.zip"/>
        </fileset>
    </attachments>
</mail>
```

Am I missing any settings?

Comment: Does the mail server need authentication? starttls? ssl? Infos in the docs from easycgi.com?

Comment: I am still getting an exception `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect` although I updated mail task as above.

Comment: Did you play with the values? starttls on/off and ssl on/off?

Comment: Yes I did but no luck. I also tried to change my compiler level to 1.7 in eclipse , tried setting `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in eclipse.ini file.

Comment: http://www.easycgi.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=1463 says to try 25 or 465 as port.

Comment: Can you keep it as answer as 465 port number and SSL TLS enabled , did send a mail successfully. Thanks a lot!